# psql doesn't accept any command on windows

Tags: cmd, postgresql-9.2, psql

I have set the PATH environment and then run psql on command prompt and then whatever command I write nothing happens, it doesn't throw any error message too.

even very basic commands as;

```
psql -l 


pg_dump -U {user-name} {source_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to finish each command with a semicolon (`;`). Until you do so, psql thinks you're still writing the same (multi-line) command.

Also, `psql -l` and `pg_dump -U {user-name} {source_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}` are not psql commands. These should be ran from your shell (without the semicolons), not from the psql terminal.

Comment: I will accept it as correct in 5 minutes but I have another question, whatever I write, I get sytax error for example;
"psql -l;"
and I get sytax error with psql
the same for "pg_dump -U user db -f out.sql"

Comment: ok nevermind that question, I found out the problem thanks for help